# Can I do knock-out/punch-through transparency with CSS fonts?

Tags: css, transparency, opacity

I would like to know if there is any way I can apply 100% transparency to text so that we can see the background picture of the page within the characters in the text.

i.e. imagine I’ve got a `<div>` with a white background, and a background image on `<body>`. I’d like to set the text inside the `<div>` so that the background image on `<body>` can be seen through the text, despite the white background on the `<div>`.

I could probably use an inverted font but I would prefer a better way to do it if there is one.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Does it have to be dynamic? The only way to do that is with an image with transparency (GIF or, better, PNG).

I'm not sure if this is what you want, but will explain it anyway.

Situation: you have a non plain background that you want to bee seen through your text.

Solution: no CSS is coming to the rescue for this. You'll have to use your trusty image editor to create a layer with text, and another layer that will be the negative of your text

This could allow you to have some interesting effects, but if you want it to be dynamic, you'll have to generate the images on the fly serverside.

This kind of trickery is currently impossible with pure CSS (might be possible with Javascript).

---

### Edit

Seeing [Paul's find on webkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2289159/css-font-transparency/2293378#2293378) got me thinking on how to fake that behavior in Firefox, Opera and IE. So far I've had good luck using the [`canvas`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial/Basic_usage) element on Firefox, and I'm trying to find some behavior in `filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft`.

So far with `canvas`, this is what I did

```
<html>
<body>
<canvas id="c" width="150" height="150">
</canvas>
<script>
ctx = document.getElementById("c").getContext("2d");
// draw rectangle filling the canvas element
ctx.fillStyle = "red";
ctx.fillRect(0,0,150,150);

// set composite property
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out'; 
// the text to be added now will "crop out" the red rectangle
ctx.strokeText("Cropping the", 10, 20);  
ctx.strokeText("red rectangle", 10, 40);  

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

by using a [detination-out compositing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Drawing_text_using_a_canvas) and [drawing text on the `canvas`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Drawing_text_using_a_canvas).

Comment: Oh! Now I get what mnml was asking. Sorry, seems obvious now.

Comment: For the record, I think this is called "punch-through" or "knockout" transparency - see e.g. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/photoshop/cs/using/WSACEF257F-5293-4f04-8267-FEFAA62E031F.html (and http://stackoverflow.com/q/7626219/20578).

Comment: Eugh, all your images no longer work. I don't suppose you can re-upload any replacements using the Stack Exchange image uploader? In the meantime, I've edited the images out, but tried to keep the value of the post... obviously, feel free to edit anything back in if I've somehow invalidated your points (and sorry if I did!).

Answer (score 22):

The state of things in 2023 - in short, we have the following options:

- Pure CSS with `mix-blend-mode`: limited to fully `white`/ `black` backgrounds on the `p` when using the `screen`/ `multiply` blend modes, or at best all 3 channels of the `background` on the `p` having higher/ lower values than the corresponding channels of any pixels of the `body` background image when using `lighten`/ `darken`
- Pure CSS with `background-clip: text`: while this has evolved from a non-standard feature into a standard one and support has massively improved, it's still limited by alignment to the `body` background + involves nesting due to buggy behaviour in Firefox
- Using an SVG `filter` to make the text pixels transparent: has excellent support all the way back to IE9 and not many limitations

In detail:

## Pure CSS: `mix-blend-mode`

This is very straightforward, the relevant code is just:

```
p {
    background: #fff;
    color: #000;
    mix-blend-mode: screen
}
```

Anything else is just unrelated layout/ prettifying fluff, not affecting getting the effect we want.

Note the snippet below only works properly if you have a fully `white` background (which may or may not have semi-transparency).

```css
html, body { display: grid }

html { height: 100% }

body {
  background: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1506383631675-0b110111327b?w=1400) 50%/ cover
}

p {
  place-self: center;
  padding: 0 0.125em;
  width: min-content;
  background: #fff;
  font: 900 clamp(1.25em, 25vmin, 25em)/ 1.125 sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  mix-blend-mode: screen
}
```

```html
<p contenteditable>Hello, world!</p>
```

### What's happening here?

Blending is an operation applied when we have two layers one on top of the other, on a per pixel and, in some cases (those we care about here), per channel basis.

[image: Illustration showing two corresponding pixels of the two layers being blended, which results in the corresponding pixel of the resulting layer.]

What any blend mode we might consider for such an effect does is th following: take every pixel of the element it's applied on (the `p` in this case) and the corresponding pixel of what's behind (the `body` background image in this case) and perform a computation involving the decimal representations of the percentage RGB channel values of the two corresponding pixels.

### How the `screen` blend mode works

In the case of the `screen` blend mode, if C₁ is a generic channel (R,G, or B, doesn't matter, the formula is the same) of a top layer pixel and C₀ is a generic channel value of the corresponding pixel in the bottom layer, the formula is as follows:

```
1 - (1 - C₁)·(1 - C₀)
```

Let's say the pixel at the intersection between the *i*th column of pixels and the *j*th row of pixels of the `p` element is a `black` one, corresponding to the actual text (that is `rgb(0%, 0%, 0%)`, all three channel values at `0%`). Let's say the corresponding pixel in the `body` background image is `rgb(41%, 55%, 91%)` - a sort of greyish blue.

Then the resulting RGB channels of that pixel after the `screen` blend mode operation are:

```
1 - (1 - 0)·(1 - .41) = 1 - 1·.59 = 1 - .59 = .41
1 - (1 - 0)·(1 - .55) = 1 - 1·.45 = 1 - .45 = .55
1 - (1 - 0)·(1 - .91) = 1 - 1·.09 = 1 - .09 = .91
```

That is, the exact same channel values as for the pixel in the `body` background image!

In general, when a pixel in one of the two layers is `black` and we use the `screen` blend mode, then the result of blending is the RGB value of the pixel in the other layer (not the one with the `black` pixel).

This is because when we have a `black` pixel, all its three channels are at `0%`, `0` in decimal representation, so either the `1 - C₁` or the `1 - C₀` part (depending in which of the two layers the pixels is `black`) is `1 - 0 = 1`, thus making the entire product part equal to the other factor, which is the complement of the channel value of the pixel in the other layer. And then complementing the complement (`1 - (1 - a) = a`), we get the initial value of the channel in the other layer.

Now let's say the pixel at the intersection between the *i*th column of pixels and the *j*th row of pixels of the `p` element is a `white` one, corresponding to the `background` (that is `rgb(100%, 100%, 100%)`, all three channel values maxed out at `100%`). Let's say the corresponding pixel in the background image the same greyish blue `rgb(41%, 55%, 91%)`.

Then the resulting RGB channels of that pixel after the `screen` blend mode operation are:

```
1 - (1 - 1)·(1 - .41) = 1 - 0·.59 = 1 - 0 = 1
1 - (1 - 1)·(1 - .55) = 1 - 0·.45 = 1 - 0 = 1
1 - (1 - 1)·(1 - .91) = 1 - 0·.09 = 1 - 0 = 1
```

That is, `rgb(100%, 100%, 100%)` or `white`!

In general, when a pixel in one of the two layers is `white` and we use the `screen` blend mode, then the result of blending is also `white`.

This is because when we have a `white` pixel, all its three channels are maxed out at `100%`, `1` in decimal representation, so either the `1 - C₁` or the `1 - C₀` part (depending in which of the two layers the pixel is `white`) is `1 - 1 = 0`, thus making the entire product part `0` and the end result `1` (or `100%`). And all three channel values maxed out at `100%`, that means `white`.

### Where the `screen` approach breaks

This also means that for any `background` of our `p` that's not fully `white`, this approach fails.

Let's say our `p` has a peachpuff background, something that's still very light to contrast with a dark background, that is `rgb(100%, 86%, 73%)`. Replacing in our formula (and considering the same RGB value for the corresponding background pixel), we have the following for the three channels:

```
1 - (1 - 1)·(1 - .41) = 1 - 0·.59 = 1 - 0 = 1
1 - (1 - .86)·(1 - .55) = 1 - .14·.45 = 1 - .063 = .937
1 - (1 - .73)·(1 - .91) = 1 - .17·.09 = 1 - .0153 = .9847
```

So the result is `rgb(100%, 93.7%, 98.47%)`, which is different from the peachpuff `background` we started with, `rgb(100%, 86%, 73%)`. They're both reddish and very light, but they're different and this difference depends on the RGB channels of the `body` background underneath.

The screenshot below illustrates this problem we run into if we want any `background` that's not fully `white` for our `p`:

[image: Screenshot illustrating how the p background, now not fully white anymore, is blended with the body background underneath to create a peachpuff tinted version of it.]

And this peachpuff is a very light, a very close to `white` option for the `background` of our `p`. The darker the `background`, the more obvious the problem. Here's `crimson` in action:

[image: Screenshot illustrating how the background blending is worse/ more obvious with a darker p background.]

Yikes!

### `lighten` - maybe another acceptable option?

Now if the `body` background image is very dark (just dark, but  around the same channel(s) as the `background` we want for our `p` might work too), we might get away with changing the blend mode to `lighten`.

For example, something like below, where the `body` background image is just dark greens, while the we've set `background: lightgreen` for our `p`:

```css
html, body { display: grid }

html { height: 100% }

body {
  background: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1533563906091-fdfdffc3e3c4?w=1400) 50%/ cover
}

p {
  place-self: center;
  padding: 0 0.125em;
  width: min-content;
  background: lightgreen;
  font: 900 clamp(1.25em, 25vmin, 25em)/ 1.125 sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  mix-blend-mode: lighten
}
```

```html
<p contenteditable>Hello, world!</p>
```

### How the `lighten` blend mode works

In the case of the `lighten` blend mode, if C₁ is a generic channel (R,G, or B, again, it doesn't matter, the formula is the same) of a top layer pixel and C₀ is a generic channel value of the corresponding pixel in the bottom layer, the formula is as follows:

```
max(C₁, C₀)
```

Really, that's it!

Let's say the pixel at the intersection between the *i*th column of pixels and the *j*th row of pixels of the `p` element is a `black` one, corresponding to the actual text (that is `rgb(0%, 0%, 0%)`, all three channel values at `0%`). Let's say the corresponding pixel in the `body` background image is `rgb(4%, 13%, 6%)` - a very dark green.

Then the resulting RGB channels of that pixel after the `lighten` blend mode operation are:

```
max(0, .04) = .04
max(0, .13) = .13
max(0, .06) = .06
```

Again that's the exact same channel values as for the pixel in the `body` background image!

This is because when we have a `black` pixel, all its three channels are at `0%`, `0` in decimal representation. And any other channel value, which is always in the `[0, 1]` range is at least as big as `0` - any number from `0` to `1` is greater or equal to `0`. So the maximum between `0` and a value in the `[0, 1]` interval is always equal to the value in the `[0, 1]` interval.

Now let's say the pixel at the intersection between the *i*th column of pixels and the *j*th row of pixels of the `p` element is a `lightgreen` one, corresponding to the `background` of the `p` (that is `rgb(57%, 93%, 57%)`). Let's say the corresponding pixel in the background image is the same very dark green - `rgb(4%, 13%, 6%)`.

Then the resulting RGB channels of that pixel after the `lighten` blend mode operation are:

```
max(.57, .04) = .57
max(.93, .13) = .93
max(.57, .06) = .57
```

That's the same as the `lightgreen` we chose as the `background` of the `p`!

Now the `background` we've chosen here for the `body` is very dark, which means the channel values of its pixels are very close to zero, so we have a pretty good chance of making this work with a lot of `background` options for our `p`.

For example, even if we were to chose something like `hotpink` for the `background` of our `p`, its channel values (`rgb(100%, 41%, 71%)`) are still bigger than those of the pixels in our very dark background, so the result of blending with it is still `hotpink`.

### Where the `lighten` approach breaks

However, if we were to choose something like a `background: red` for our `p`, this approach also fails, as the green and blue channel values are `0` for `red` (`rgb(100%, 0%, 0%)`) - that is, lower than even the very low values we have for our dark green background image on the `body`. You can see below how the result of blending wouldn't be `rgb(100%, 0%, 0%)` anymore:

```
max(1, .04) = 1
max(0, .13) = .13
max(0, .06) = .06
```

And here's a screenshot of what it would look like:

[image]

Ugh...

And it would only be worse if the layer underneath, the `background-image` on the `body`, wasn't as dark. Take the first image we used in our examples - not even the `hotpink` background that worked for our `p` with the darker `body` background image would still work out now.

[image]

### At the other lightness end

Let's also see a pure CSS way for the case where the `background-image` on the `body` is a very bright one and the `background` of our `p` is a very dark one.

Since we want to see through to the `background` of `body` in the area occupied by the actual text letters, we can choose any initial RGB value we want for them and, in this case, we choose `white`.

So in the case when we start with `background: black` on our `p`, we may use the `multiply` blend mode.

```css
html, body { display: grid }

html { height: 100% }

body {
  background: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1489069313310-63735a4f3010?w=1400) 50%/ cover
}

p {
  place-self: center;
  padding: 0 0.125em;
  width: min-content;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  font: 900 clamp(1.25em, 25vmin, 25em)/ 1.125 sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  mix-blend-mode: multiply
}
```

```html
<p contenteditable>Hello, world!</p>
```

### How the `multiply` blend mode works

In the case of the `multiply` blend mode, if C₁ is a generic channel (R,G, or B, doesn't matter) of a top layer pixel and C₀ is a generic channel value of the corresponding pixel in the bottom layer, the formula is:

```
C₁·C₀
```

Let's say the pixel at the intersection between the *i*th column of pixels and the *j*th row of pixels of the `p` element is a `white` one, corresponding to the actual text (that is `rgb(100%, 100%, 100%)`, all three channel values maxed out at `0%`). Let's say the corresponding pixel in the `body` background image is `rgb(45%, 77%, 80%)` - a sort of light cyan.

Then the resulting RGB channels of that pixel after the `multiply` blend mode operation are:

```
1·.45 = .45
1·.77 = .77
1·.80 = .80
```

That is, the exact same channel values as for the pixel in the `body` background image!

In general, when a pixel in one of the two layers is `white` and we use the `multiply` blend mode, then the result of blending is the RGB value of the pixel in the other layer (not the one with the `white` pixel).

This is because when we have a `white` pixel, all its three channels are maxed out at `100%`, `1` in decimal representation, which makes the entire product equal to the other factor.

Now let's say the pixel at the intersection between the *i*th column of pixels and the *j*th row of pixels of the `p` element is a `black` one, corresponding to the `background` (that is `rgb(100%, 100%, 100%)`, all three channel values maxed out at `100%`). Let's say the corresponding pixel in the background image the same light cyan `rgb(45%, 77%, 80%)`.

Then the resulting RGB channels of that pixel after the `multiply` blend mode operation are:

```
0·.45 = 0
0·.77 = 0
0·.80 = 0
```

That is, `rgb(0%, 0%, 0%)` or `black`!

In general, when a pixel in one of the two layers is `black` and we use the `multiply` blend mode, then the result of blending is also `black`.

This is because when we have a `black` pixel, all its three channels are at `0%`, `0` in decimal representation, so either the `C₁` or the `C₀` (depending in which of the two layers the pixel is `black`) is `0`, thus making the entire product/ end result `0` (or `0%`). And all three channel values at `0%`, that means `black`.

### Where the `multiply` approach breaks

For any `background` of our `p` that's not fully `black`, this approach fails.

Let's say our `p` has an indigo `background` (`rgb(29%, 0%, 51%)`), something that's still very dark to contrast with a bright `body` background image. Replacing in our formula (and considering the same `rgb(45%, 77%, 80%)` value for the corresponding background pixel), we have the following for the three channels:

```
.29·.45 = .1305
0·.77 = 0
.51·.80 = .408
```

The result is `rgb(13.05%, 0%, 40.8%)`, which is different from the indigo `background` we started with, `rgb(29%, 0%, 51%)`. They're both dark, but they're different and this difference depends on the RGB channels of the `body` background underneath.

The screenshot below illustrates this problem we run into if we want any `background` that's not fully `black` for our `p` when using the `multiply` blend mode:

[image]

The lighter the `background` of the `p`, the more obvious the problem is.

### `darken` - maybe another acceptable option?

Now if the `body` background image is very bright (just bright, but  around the same channel(s) as the `background` we want for our `p` might work too), we might get away with changing the blend mode to `darken`.

For example, something like below, where the `body` background image is mostly just light orange-pink, while the we've set `background: maroon` for our `p`:

```css
html, body { display: grid }

html { height: 100% }

body {
  background: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1516464278939-6c47180c46eb?w=1400) 50%/ cover
}

p {
  place-self: center;
  padding: 0 0.125em;
  width: min-content;
  background: maroon;
  color: #fff;
  font: 900 clamp(1.25em, 25vmin, 25em)/ 1.125 sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  mix-blend-mode: darken
}
```

```html
<p contenteditable>Hello, world!</p>
```

### How the `darken` blend mode works

In the case of the `darken` blend mode, if C₁ is a generic channel (R,G, or B, again, it doesn't matter, the formula is the same) of a top layer pixel and C₀ is a generic channel value of the corresponding pixel in the bottom layer, the formula is as follows:

```
min(C₁, C₀)
```

Again, a very simple formula.

Let's say the pixel at the intersection between the *i*th column of pixels and the *j*th row of pixels of the `p` element is a `white` one, corresponding to the actual text (that is `rgb(100%, 100%, 100%)`, all three channel values maxed out at `100%`). Let's say the corresponding pixel in the `body` background image is `rgb(100%, 49%, 44%)` - a kind of light salmon.

Then the resulting RGB channels of that pixel after the `darken` blend mode operation are:

```
min(1, 1) = 1
min(1, .49) = .49
min(1, .44) = .44
```

Again that's the exact same channel values as for the pixel in the `body` background image!

This is because when we have a `white` pixel, all its three channels are at maxed out `100%`, `1` in decimal representation. And any other channel value, which is always in the `[0, 1]` range is at least as small as `1` - any number from `0` to `1` is smaller or equal to `1`. So the minimum between `1` and a value in the `[0, 1]` interval is always equal to the value in the `[0, 1]` interval.

Now let's say the pixel at the intersection between the *i*th column of pixels and the *j*th row of pixels of the `p` element is a `maroon` one, corresponding to the `background` of the `p` (that is `rgb(50%, 0%, 0%)`). Let's say the corresponding pixel in the background image is the same light salmon - `rgb(100%, 49%, 44%)`.

Then the resulting RGB channels of that pixel after the `darken` blend mode operation are:

```
min(.5, 1) = .5
min(0, .49) = 0
min(0, .44) = 0
```

That's the same as the `maroon` we chose as the `background` of the `p`!

### Where the `darken` approach breaks

However, if we were to choose something like a `background: indigo` for our `p`, this approach also fails, as the blue channel value is `51%` for `indigo` (`rgb(29%, 0%, 51%)`) - that is, lower than even the very low values we have for our dark green background image on the `body`. You can see below how the result of blending wouldn't be `rgb(29%, 0%, 51%)` anymore:

```
min(.29, 1) = .29
min(0, .49) = 0
min(.51, .44) = .44
```

And here's a screenshot of what it would look like - even worse than when the same `background: indigo` on the `p` fails with the `multiply` blend mode:

[image]

## Pure CSS: `background-clip: text`

This has already been mentioned, so I'd normally avoid going into it again, especially since it's not a solution I would use given its scroll complications, but so much has changed in the decade that passed since the previous answers!

**`background-clip: text` is now standard, supported by all browsers**, doesn't require the `-webkit-` prefix anymore in any of the modern browsers (or maybe only needs it on mobile, where I haven't tested, as I myself don't have a smartphone and in my environment don't have access to a smartphone that's less than 10 years old and running old versions of everything) and can be used in the shorthand.

```css
html, body { display: grid }

html { height: 100% }

body { background: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1489069313310-63735a4f3010?w=1400') 50%/ cover fixed }

p {
    place-self: center;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0 .125em;
    width: min-content;
    background: black 50%/ cover text fixed;
    background-image: inherit;
    color: transparent;
    font: 900 clamp(1.25em, 25vmin, 25em)/ 1.125 sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    
    &::before {
        position: absolute;
        inset: 0;
        z-index: -1;
        background: indigo;
        content: ''
    }
}
```

```html
<p contenteditable>Hello, world</p>
```

No need for any workarounds to emulate it in other browsers, such as `-moz-element()` in Firefox (prefixed version of the standard `element()` version, which Chromium browsers haven't implemented and probably won't implement due to security concerns).

The problem with this is it requires to set the same `background-image` on both the `body` and the `p` element and the images need to be aligned. Something that's easily achievable with `background-attachment: fixed`, but this means the `background` cannot scroll with the page. May be totally fine in some cases, but not in others.

The even more annoying problem with this is that we need to use up a pseudo-element due to a [Firefox bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1481498) soon old enough to go to school.

Without this bug, this little bit of code would do it:

```
body { background: url(myimage.jpg) 50%/ cover fixed }

p {
    background: 
        url(myimage.jpg) 50%/ cover text fixed, 
        linear-gradient(indigo 0 0);
    color: transparent
}
```

Note the `background-clip: text` approach means we run into problems if we need to scroll.

## Using an SVG `filter`: create real text transparency

The idea is the following: if we don't want our background to be `black`, then we make our text `black` (that is, having all three RGB channels zeroed `rgb(0, 0, 0)`) and we apply a `filter` that gives us a result whose alpha channel is computed out of the RGBA channels of its input as follows:

```
v·R + v·G + v·B + 0·A + 0 = v·(R + G + B) + 0 = v·(R + G + B)
```

This means the alpha of the result is `0` wherever the RGB channels of the input are all `0`, so wherever the pixels of the input are `rgb(0, 0, 0)` (that is `black`). In our case, that's the text.

```css
html, body { display: grid }

html { height: 100% }

body {
    background: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1700607687506-5149877683e8?w=1400') 50%/ cover fixed
}

svg[width='0'][height='0'] { position: fixed }

p {
    place-self: center;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0 .125em;
    width: min-content;
    background: white;
    font: 900 clamp(1.25em, 25vmin, 25em)/ 1.125 sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    filter: url(#punch-through)
}
```

```html
<svg width='0' height='0'>
  <filter id='punch-through'>
    <feColorMatrix values=' 1   0   0 0 0
                            0   1   0 0 0
                            0   0   1 0 0
                          999 999 999 0 0'/>
  </filter>
</svg>

<p contenteditable>Hello, world!</p>
```

Now you may be wondering what's up with those values in that formula, what's the deal with the matrix, how are they connected...

```
v v v 0 0
```

are the values on the fourth (final) row of the matrix `values` for `feColorMatrix`. `v` is a large value, let's throw in a random `999`, in order to ensure the result alpha outside of the fully `black` areas (that is, outside the text) is always ≥ `1` (which means fully opaque).

The other three rows give us the RGB channels and those we just want to leave unchanged. The red channel of the output is just `1` multiplied with red channel of the input plus a bunch of zeroes and the same is valid for the green and blue channels.

```
1·R + 0·G + 0·B + 0·A + 0 = R + 0 + 0 + 0 + 0 = R
0·R + 1·G + 0·B + 0·A + 0 = 0 + G + 0 + 0 + 0 = G
0·R + 0·G + 1·B + 0·A + 0 = 0 + 0 + B + 0 + 0 = B
```

This means the first three matrix rows are:

```
1 0 0 0 0
0 1 0 0 0
0 0 1 0 0
```

(`1` diagonally and `0` elsewhere)

Now... depending on how picky you are, you might be happy with this result... or not!

I'm not happy with it.

There's still some black along the edges and it looks kinda rough.

Fortunately, in this particular case, the `background` of our `p` is `white`, which means we're maxing out all three RGB channels at `100%`, that's our input for them, that's what we want the output to be, no need to even bother with even something as simple as multiplying the input channel values with `1` anymore!

Just drop the decimal representation (`1` for `100%`) on the last column of the matrix and zero everything else for the first three rows, which basically means this is what gets computed (`R`, `G`, `B` and `A` are all `1` and that's something we know beforehand):

```
0·R + 0·G + 0·B + 0·A + 0 = 0·1 + 0·1 + 0·1 + 0·1 + 0 = 0 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 1 = 1
0·R + 0·G + 0·B + 0·A + 0 = 0·1 + 0·1 + 0·1 + 0·1 + 0 = 0 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 1 = 1
0·R + 0·G + 0·B + 0·A + 0 = 0·1 + 0·1 + 0·1 + 0·1 + 0 = 0 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 1 = 1
```

As for the final row, the one giving us the alpha of the result, it's the same as before, we just make `v` equal to `1/3` since we know the `background` RGB channels in this case are maxed out at `100%` (`1`), so multiplying them with `1` and then adding up the products won't give us a subunitary value for the result alpha (`1` and greater means fully opaque, in the `(0, 1)` interval means semitransparent and `0` means fully transparent) outside the actual text, which is `black`, so all channels are `0`.

So for the `white` background, the alpha computes to:

```
v·R + v·G + v·B + 0·A + 0 = ⅓·1 + ⅓·1 + ⅓·1 + 0·1 + 0 = ⅓ + ⅓ + ⅓ + 0 + 0 = 3/3 = 1
```

while for the `black` text, the alpha computes to:

```
v·R + v·G + v·B + 0·A + 0 = ⅓·0 + ⅓·0 + ⅓·0 + 0·1 + 0 = 0 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 0 = 0
```

Now... at the edges of the text, we have some pixels that are neither fully `black` nor fully `white` and those give us some semitransparency there to smoothen out the edges, make them look nice.

```css
html, body { display: grid }

html { height: 100% }

body {
    background: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1700607687506-5149877683e8?w=1400') 50%/ cover fixed
}

svg[width='0'][height='0'] { position: fixed }

p {
    place-self: center;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0 .125em;
    width: min-content;
    background: white;
    font: 900 clamp(1.25em, 25vmin, 25em)/ 1.125 sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    filter: url(#punch-through)
}
```

```html
<svg width='0' height='0'>
  <filter id='punch-through'>
    <feColorMatrix values=' 0   0   0 0 1
                            0   0   0 0 1
                            0   0   0 0 1
                          .33 .33 .33 0 0'/>
  </filter>
</svg>

<p contenteditable>Hello, world!</p>
```

But what if we don't want a `white` background? No problem, we can easily set any other solid `background` in the SVG `filter`!

We just flood the entire `filter` area with the desired background and give it the alpha of the punched through `white` layer.

```css
html, body { display: grid }

html { height: 100% }

body {
    background: 
        url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1700607687506-5149877683e8?w=1400') 
            50%/ cover fixed
}

svg[width='0'][height='0'] { position: fixed }

p {
    place-self: center;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0 .125em;
    width: min-content;
    background: white;
    font: 900 clamp(1.25em, 25vmin, 25em)/ 1.125 sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    filter: url(#punch-through)
}
```

```html
<svg width='0' height='0'>
  <filter id='punch-through'>
    <feColorMatrix values=' 0   0   0 0 1
                            0   0   0 0 1
                            0   0   0 0 1
                          .33 .33 .33 0 0' result='punched'/>
    <feFlood flood-color='darkslategrey'/>
    <feComposite operator='in' in2='punched'/>
  </filter>
</svg>

<p contenteditable>Hello, world!</p>
```

The semitransparent `#2f4f4fa4` as a `flood-color` works just as well.

We can even replace the `white` background on our `p` with something like:

```
repeating-linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 0 4px, white 0 2rem)
```

for a `background` on our `p` that has fully opaque and fully transparent parts - try it out!

Answer (score 6):

I’m not exactly clear what you’re asking (100% transparency means that something’s invisible, and invisible text isn’t generally a great idea), but in general:

1. The CSS `opacity` property applies to an entire element, not just its text. So if you have this HTML:

   ```
   <div class="opacity-50">
       This is a div with a background colour and 50% opacity
   </div>
   ```

   And this CSS:

   ```
   .opacity-50 {
       background: #ccc;
       color: #000;
       opacity: 0.5;
   }
   ```

   Then both its background and its text will have 50% opacity.
2. `rgba` colour values allow you to specify semi-transparent colours. So, if you have this HTML:

   ```
   <div class="text-opacity-50">
       This is a div with semi-transparent text
   </div>
   ```

   And this CSS:

   ```
   .text-opacity-50 {
       background: #ccc;
       color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
   }
   ```

   Then only its text will have 50% opacity.

I think `rgba` colour values are supported by slightly fewer browses than `opacity`.

Comment: What I meant was:
[transparent-text/InsideA/colored-Div]-[colored-background]

thanks for the explanation

Comment: I’m not super-clear on what that combination of punctuation means either, to be honest.

Comment: I was just trying to explain the "layers" of what I want to do

Answer (score 4):

Ah — if you’re talking about “punch-through” transparency, no, CSS doesn’t do this.

*Except for WebKit* (the rendering engine in Safari and Chrome), which has a totally custom, made-up-by-Dave-Hyatt, not-even-in-CSS-3 property value, [`-webkit-background-clip: text;`](http://webkit.org/blog/164/background-clip-text/).

No other browser other than Safari and Chrome supports it.

Comment: +1 Interesting find! Confirmed on Chrome. No other browser (not even Konqueror) supports it right now. I imagine that you can fake it with some trickery on IE, and on Firefox it could be done with javascript (I know I've seen something like that somewhere). As for Opera...

Comment: Very nice, I would use that if firefox was using webkit. I'm going to stick with voyager's answer for now I guess.

Comment: Yeah, WebKit is the place where CSS innovation is happening fastest. (Although most of their innovations do seem to be Mac OS X internals being exposed by CSS, which I guess is sort of cheating — Mozilla doesn’t sell an operating system, so they don’t have a similar body of code to call on.)

Comment: Oh — could you fake this with JavaScript in Firefox? I can’t imagine how.

Comment: On IE, I imagine that there is something in `filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft` that you could use. On FF you might be able to do some Canvas or SVG trickery.

Comment: For FF: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Drawing_text_using_a_canvas + https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial/Compositing (source-out compositing)

Answer (score 1):

You can spent the time to make your own font with InkScape and IcoMoon and make a negative knocked out font, then your letters can be see trough! I used this technique for some see trough Icons.

Answer (score 0):

Why not try to set the DIV's background image to a completely transparent GIF?

http://www.pageresource.com/dhtml/csstut9.htm

Answer (score 0):

Using a .png without background is a good method. In Photoshop you can save for the web.

or in css:

```
#div
{
    background:transparent;
    color:whatever;

}
```