# How do I make punch-through transparent text in HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css, transparency

I have a div which has css `background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85);`. Centered in that div is the title of the page. I want to make the title see through (knockout, punch-through, however you want to call it. i.e. see past the div's background black to the background image of the page). The only method of doing that that I have come up with is using an image with the div's background and transparent text and seperate the header part into blocks.

```
///////////////////////////////////////////////
//  (empty)    //  TITLE IMAGE //   (empty)  //
///////////////////////////////////////////////
```

The problem is that I dont know how to create the empty divs such that the image will remain centered (the empty divs need to be there to add the black background). Is there a different way to either do the see through text that doesnt have this problem or a way to center the image div with the empty divs?

EDIT: For an example of the effect that I am trying to achieve, look here:
http://www.showandtell-graphics.com/layer-knockout.html

Comment: Possibly see also http://stackoverflow.com/a/2289440/20578

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can not do this directly; You should use an image for this, or svg might do the trick but that's a hell of a lot more complicated and browsers do not all support it that well.

Comment: This is why I said that Im using an image, the problem is: how do I keep the image centered with the two divs on each side filling up the space (in order to show the background)?

Comment: its ok, this is unrelated to the question, mostly. thanks though

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to do this

```
<div> 
    <h1>Title</h1>
</div>
```

Place the `background-image` on the `div`

The `h1` will be transparent by default.

To center the title, use `text-align:center`

To center the background image, you can use `background-position:center`

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/EQDZd/

Comment: I think you misunderstood what I meant by see-through. I added an example in the question.

Comment: That example clarifies things, @chacham15.  I'm not sure that is possible with just CSS.  Why not just create the image with the see-through text and make that the `h1`?

Comment: This is why I said that Im using an image, the problem is: how do I keep the image centered with the two divs on each side filling up the space (in order to show the background)?