# How can you achieve a "knockout" effect using CSS?

Tags: html, css

**UPDATE -** Pretty sure I figured this out. The code is somewhat long, but I threw a page up here so you can view the source: http://www.sorryhumans.com/knockout-header

The concept was based on: http://algemeenbekend.nl/misc/challenge_gerben_v2.html and then adapted for my needs.

The header is responsive and knocked out. (Please ignore the bad, 1 minute responsive bg image implementation!). This implementation also does not use any CSS3, so I would imagine that there wouldn't be many issues with compatibility.

The only issue I find is that when the browser width is an odd number (e.g. 1393px) in Chrome there is a 1px gap between the right hand fluid column and the main center column. I don't see this issue in the latest version of Firefox, Internet Explorer, or when the width is an even number (e.g. 1394px in Chrome). Any ideas?

**Original Question:**
I'm attempting to code a header that I designed, but am unable to figure out how to get the effect I'm looking for. Please look at the attached image (No, this is not actually what I'm working on :) just an example!)

[image: example picture]

The photo is a full-width responsive photo. The header is full-width, but its contents are on a responsive grid that does not exceed some arbitrary size (shown by the black lines), but can scale down. I can accomplish all of this, but what I am having trouble figuring out is how to make the make the header bar be transparent where the logo would be. In other words, rather than having the logo be on top of the bar, I would like to "knock it out" of the header.

Is this even possible?

Comment: Using a `.png` is the easiest way to do it, particularly for a logo.

Comment: @Sean What have you tried? have toy looked at the css `opacity`?

Comment: Using an image is the only method I can think of as well. [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7626738/1405830) seems to agree, but also mentions SVG as an alternative. I'm interested in knowing if there's another method though.

Comment: @JamesKhoury The only way that I can think of doing this is by having 5 divs: 2 "side" divs which have the transparent background and can stretch on to infinity, 1 logo div which is a png of the transparent background with the logo knocked out, one div which will serve as the content area, and one div to hold the logo and the content. Kind of like this:
[    side     ][ [logo] [     content     ] ][    side     ]

But, I don't think this is possible without javascript, right? If I have one container div, the transparent "knockout" effect will take the color of the container.

Comment: There is support in WebKit for [CSS Masks](http://www.webkit.org/blog/181/css-masks/) (see also http://caniuse.com/css-masks), but you can only use an image as a mask, not text.

Comment: @SeanLinehan I'm sorry I had misunderstood the question. I would use an image base solution. for the centering that depends on what browsers you want to support.

Comment: Nicely done sir, though I was disappointed you had to fall back on plain black text.

Answer (score 4):

There's no inherent support for knockout effects, so you'll have to have the text as part of an image.

The easiest way to do this would be to have the background behind the knockout effect be the solid part of the image. You can create a `.png` with a solid background and transparency where you want the knockout effect, and use css `opacity` to make the entire header partially transparent. You will need to set up the header with multiple sections so that the sections that are not images (i.e. outside the black bars) have a background color, while the sections with images do not.

Very roughly:

```
<div id="outerHeaderWithOpacity">
  <div class="hasBackground">Left side, will stretch</div>
  <div class="noBackground">Image(s) go here</div>
  <div class="hasBackground">As many sets as you need</div>
  <div class="noBackground">Image(s) go here</div>
  <div class="hasBackground">Right side, will stretch</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is what I was roughly thinking as well, but I couldn't figure out what the CSS would look like. Referencing the original image, the area in the header between the black bars should remain centered regardless of screen size. Can you help me figure that part out? Thank you very much for your help so far!

Comment: @SeanLinehan You could use jQuery to set the widths [with something like this](http://jsfiddle.net/VPU9A/), but the `flexbox` method in the other answer seems far more elegant.

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/GZ8Xv/

not the prettiest solution but using the experimental css3 flexbox: *(with `display: table` fallback)*

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="left"><br /></div>
    <div class="middle"><br /></div>
    <div class="right"><br /></div>
</div>
```

```
.left, .right
{
    height:100%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display:table-cell;
    display: -webkit-flexbox;
    display: -moz-flexbox;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -o-flexbox;
    -webkit-flex: 1;
}

.middle
{
    display: table-cell;
    display: -webkit-flexbox;
    width: 500px;
    height:100%;
    border: 1px solid blue
}

.wrapper
{
    display: table;

    display: -webkit-flexbox;
    display: -moz-flexbox;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -o-flexbox;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -moz-box-orient: horizontal;
    -ms-box-orient: horizontal;
    -o-box-orient: horizontal;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
}
```

**PLEASE NOTE:** the flexbox w3c spec is still in flux and could change a third time. I only tested this in IE9 (both IE9 and IE8 modes. Does not work in IE7 mode) and Chrome 20 and 22

A few minor changes: http://jsfiddle.net/GZ8Xv/2/ and you have your 5 div layout without javascript.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to help! I think I found a decent solution that doesn't use CSS3 which I've updated the original post with if you are interested.

Comment: @SeanLinehan Im glad you found a answer. It would be good to post your solution as an answer and mark it as accepted. This way others can find your solution easier.