# Make the text part of a div transparent

Tags: html, css

I need to find a way to view the image behind a div through the text in the div:

E.g.

[image]

I have the font as a web font. Is this possible without having to do image replacement?

Comment: This question is a duplicate of many other questions. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2289159/can-i-do-knock-out-punch-through-transparency-with-css-fonts?lq=1 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7626219/how-do-i-make-punch-through-transparent-text-in-html-css?lq=1

Comment: Both those questions are very out of date. It can be done with CSS these days eg. http://css-tricks.com/image-under-text/

Comment: Yeah I saw that but unfortunately it doesn't quite do what I need it to. I need to be able to see the background of a larger containing div, rather than just seeing a background image on the actual element.

Comment: @JamesPlayer you can use the same technique by setting the same image as the background for the container and the text as in [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/koala_dev/dxqeysny/), the only issue will be if the container div is not at the top of the page then you'll need to manually adjust the background position in the text

Comment: I don't understand why you don't make a png of the white, knock it out, and then stick it on top of the image, why would you need to do image replacement.

Comment: @Christina will that auto-adjust to changes in the text? Can you provide a codepen of what you mean?

Comment: No it won't. It's an image over the image. You can't do what you're asking in css.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the ways to accomplish your specification using only CSS is to overlap the two background images perfectly thereby creating a "transparent" effect that you've described.  Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/v780v1Ln/.

Note: paddings and such alter the dimensions of the element and affect the coordinates that must be set for background images.

HTML:

```
<div id = "wrapper">
    <h1><span>DRD</span></h1>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
    background: #e2e2e2;
}

#wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    width: 70%;
    height: 50%;
    top: 25%;
    left: 15%;
    background: url(http://i58.tinypic.com/2vdieso.jpg)
                no-repeat
                0 0/500px 362px;
}

#wrapper > h1 {
    background-color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0 55px 0 25px;
    top: 25px;
    left: 25px;
}

#wrapper > h1 > span {
    font: bold 70px/1 Sans-Serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background: url(http://i58.tinypic.com/2vdieso.jpg)
                no-repeat
                -45px -25px/500px 362px;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    background-clip: text;
    color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: `background-clip: text` is supported in WebKit Browsers and Opera.  There is no FF support: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-clip.

Comment: This works well. I've done an example with centered text and a fallback for non webkit-browsers: http://jsfiddle.net/g2tf68v7/23/

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me and my project. by stacking the images on top of each other I was essentially able to mirror them even when the position of the box may change

```
background-image: url("background.jpeg");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-position: center;
background-size: cover;
-webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
-webkit-background-clip: text;
 background-clip: text;
```