# CSS knockout text effect + text-shadow on a background image

Tags: css

How would you achieve such effect in pure CSS ?

[image]

I easily found ressources to create a knockout text effect, but the challenge here is to combine classic knockout text effect [like this](https://css-tricks.com/how-to-do-knockout-text/) with inner text shadow AND transparency to let the background image visible.

Experimental rules allowed. SVG too, but I'd prefer CSS :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I do knock-out/punch-through transparency with CSS fonts?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2289159/can-i-do-knock-out-punch-through-transparency-with-css-fonts)

Comment: Thanks guys. I updated my post. I'd like to combine knockout text effect with text-shadow. I don't think this is a duplicate.

Comment: Oh I tried a lot of possibilities and did a lot of researches on Google and CodePen.

Comment: If your background is solid you can do it [with text shadows](http://dabblet.com/gist/e1c36b4f172630e8d2bd), but this method really doesn't work with non-solid backgrounds (as demonstrated)

Comment: This isn't a "too broad" question. The OP explicitly shows the effect wanted with a image and it's something achievable with CSS but not so simple, i.e. a very good question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting from *Hunter Turner* answer, it's possible to improve it with [CSS Blend Mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode). This way the background image of the container can be blended to the text, resulting in what you wanted to do. However, remember it [hasn't broad support yet](http://caniuse.com/#search=mix-blend-mode).

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: url('http://www.designbolts.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/Free-Seamless-Wood-Textures-Patterns-For-3D-Mapping-2.jpg');
  background-size: contain;
}

.container p {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 60px;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .45);
  text-shadow: 4px 4px 6px #fff, 0 0 0 #000, 4px 4px 6px #fff;
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>Hello World</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This is awesome. Why didn't I think of blend modes before :) Thank you.

Comment: Great answer! Didn't know about mix-blend-mode :D

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by using `rgba()` for the color, paired with `text-shadow`.

**CSS**

```
color: rgba(255,0,0, 0.4);
text-shadow: 4px 4px 6px red, 0 0 0 #000, 4px 4px 6px red;
```

**Example**

```css
html,body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  background-color: red;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.container p {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 60px;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: rgba(255,0,0, 0.4);
  text-shadow: 4px 4px 6px red, 0 0 0 #000, 4px 4px 6px red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>Hello World</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! That's what I achieved so far too, but the problem is that I need a non-solid background behind the text.

Comment: Yeah that is an issue. Your background seems to be almost all one color. Maybe you can do something [like this] (https://jsfiddle.net/ndebq1c9/) and position the background so the text is over the most neutral part. I know it's not ideal, but like I said, I think that may be the best you can do with CSS, but I'll keep looking for a better solution.

Comment: Yes, I also tried to put the same background within the text with `background-clip` but this cannot be combined with `text-shadow`. Sadly, this doesn't seem feasible with pure CSS :)

Comment: Yeah :/ Who knows! Just keep the question open and see if someone else has some ninja CSS that'll solve it ;D

Comment: Guys, it's possible to achieve with `mix-blend-mode` but not supported along all browsers yet. See my answer.